# Node JS preventing value undefined crash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a value that is determined by the user and once that value is entered it checks the corresponding value of that value in the data.json file.
The problem is that the code crashes if there is no corresponding value for the user input value.

```js
var rdata = fs.readFileSync("data.json")
var data = JSON.parse(rdata)
let name = (val[0]) //val[0] is the value that user enters
console.log(data[name].value)
```

If there is no corresponding for data[name] in data.json the code crashes. How do I prevent from undefined data[name].value from causing the code crash?

```
console.log(data[name].value)
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: use `if (data[name])` to check if it's not null first.

Comment: Use @ChrisG solution or enclose it with `try` `catch`

Comment: Wait, you have `data[filename]` but isn't it `data[name]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple approaches, as you can see by the various suggestions from other people and it depends what you want to accomplish and what your code is doing.

- You can use the or (`||`) operator to fallback to a default / safe value in case the provided input is `undefined` as follows

  ```
    let userInput; //undefined`     
    let x = userInput || "a safe value";
  ```

Essentially, "let x be whatever userInput is unless it's `undefined` (or `NaN`, `null`, ...).

- Similarly, you can do an `if` check to make sure that the value you are expecting is available and valid:

  ```
  if(userInput){
      //Happy path, userInput is valid.
  }
  else {
     // Not so happy path,  do something about it to handle the invalid value.
  }
  ```
- You can use a `try-catch` block in case you want to handle the case. There are multiple ways of throwing, catching and handling errors but if you want to inform your user that their input is invalid, you can do something like:

  ```
  try {
       //stuff may happen here
       if(userInput) {
          throw new TypeError("A useful description of why this was thrown");
       }
       //if userInput is value, then continue...
  } 
  catch(error){
      alert("Oops! Seems like the value you entered is not valid. Error:" + error);
  }
  ```

NB:
If you're not sure about what's the best approach, it would be useful if you could provide us with more code and context so we can understand how and when the value is being assigned before we can determine the best way to handle this.

It looks like you're trying to access the user's input data before the user has had a chance to type it in, in which case it would be better to refactor your code.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is that if val[0] has no corresponding value in JSON array to not interact any further and just console.log('Error')

Comment: In that case you can wrap your code with a `try-catch` block and instead of an `alert` do a `console.log(error)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `||` for [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation)

```js
const data = {
  'def.txt': {
    name: 'def'
  }
}


console.log((data['abc.txt'] || {}).name)
console.log((data['def.txt'] || {}).name)
```